# How to render child components only in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox

I am learning react, and is trying to plot a map with mapbox. I am stuck with how to render elements seperatly.

In the render part, there is a  `<div/>` element and a component `<CityWeather/>` wrapped. `div` is a reference to map. The `<Cityweather />` is an info  box which is supposed to display weather information based on lat and long. The `app.js` file render method is

```
render(){
    console.log(this.state);
    return(
        <section>
            <div className="map-container" ref={x => { this.mapContainer = x;}}/>
            <CityWeather lat={this.state.lat} lng={this.state.lng} /> 
        </section>
    );
```

The `componentDidMount()` is

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getLocation();
    mapboxgl.accessToken = "";

    const { lng, lat, zoom } = this.state;
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: this.mapContainer,
        style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
        center: [lng, lat],
        zoom: zoom
    });
   map.on("moveend", () => {
       const { lng, lat } = map.getCenter();
       this.setState({
           lng: lng.toFixed(4),
           lat: lat.toFixed(4),
           zoom: map.getZoom().toFixed(2)
       });
   });
 }
```

The `<CityWeather />` component

```
class CityWeather extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        name: ""
    };
 }
 componentDidMount() {
     console.log(this.props); // this logs only 1 time when the page loads
    fetch("api?lat=" + this.props.lat +"&lon=" +this.props.lng +       "&appid=")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {this.setState({ name: data.name });
    }); // get name from lat and long and store it in state
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="city-weather">
            <p>
                City | <span className="city">
                {this.state.name}</span>
            </p>
       </div>
    );
}
}
```

On each event the console is logging the updated latitude, longitude and zoom. Also the `<CityWeather/>` is also rendered for Ist time. After that the component is not rendered on state change.

Comment: I don't get the problem. Can you explain a little more? Do you want to render child components separately?  Or they don't render?

Comment: @Mahmoodvcs What I am trying to achieve is to render the `<CityWeather/> component only. It's rendered for one time only when the on page reload only. Not on every state change.

Comment: use shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle hook where you can check on which state change you want to update your code

Comment: So the problem is that the component `<CityWeather/>` does not get rendered after state change? Or You don't want to render it on state change? Or you don't want to re-render the div on each state change?

Comment: @Mahmoodvcs So the problem is that the component <CityWeather/> does not get rendered after state change? Yes. Or you don't want to re-render the div on each state change? No.

Comment: Well, if the `<CityWeather/>` is not updating with state change, we need to see it's code. The current code has no problem.

Comment: @Mahmoodvcs I have updated the question with the <CItyWeather/> component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have loaded weather data in `componentDidMount`. It will only run the first time that the component is rendered, Not on every state change.

This is the correct code:

```
class CityWeather extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: ""
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.load();
    }

    load(){
        console.log(this.props); // this logs only 1 time when the page loads
        fetch("api?lat=" + this.props.lat + "&lon=" + this.props.lng + "&appid=")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ name: data.name });
            }); // get name from lat and long and store it in state

    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
        if (this.props.lat !== prevProps.lat || this.props.lng !== prevProps.lng) {
            this.load();
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="city-weather">
                <p>
                    City | <span className="city">
                        {this.state.name}</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a log in the listener? I think the method was not called because you did not move. you can use timer and some mock data to test the render.